# php 5.3 --> 5.6 memcacheD extension sessions compatibility issues

Tags: php, memcached

When I upgrade from php 5.3 --> php 5.6 and use the same version of memcacheD extension with the same serialization and configuration settings the sessions are no longer valid.

Even when the same settings; my session data doesn't persist between php versions upgrades. (I have load balanced servers and was able to test between them)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/appendices.php

Comment: @Sammitch thank you for the reply. I already checked the upgrade docs and tested my code; but my question is about a very specific extension using session handling.

Comment: I just tried and it and it seems to NOT work; but would love documetnation.

Answer (score 0):

PHP serialization is not compatible between PHP 5.3 and 5.6. The PHP breaking changes says: "unserialize() will now fail if passed serialized data that has been manipulated to attempt to instantiate an object without calling its constructor."

However, I've found serialization to be just generally broken when one version deserializes what another version serializes. We ran into this issue with serialized data cached in Memcached and in database records where multiple versions of PHP were attempting to access the same serialized data.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.changed-functions.php

A solution is to not use PHP serialization and use JSON or some other standardized data serialization instead.

We had to write a "translation" step that could read both versions of data and write to the new data serialization format we were moving to (JSON in our instance).